# How to divide already split dates into two columns based on the resolution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am taking `start_date`, `end_date` & `resolution` as input from the user and I would like to split the start & end date based on the resolution as follows:

```
start_date = 2019-03-05 00:00:00
end_date = 2019-03-06 00:00:00
resolution = 15mins
```

Based on the resolution, the start and the end date must be split in intervals of the `resolution`.

This I know can be done as:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq = '15T').tolist()
dates = pd.Series(dates)
```

But this gives the result as follows:

```
0
2018-01-01 00:00:00
2018-01-01 00:15:00
2018-01-01 00:30:00
2018-01-01 00:45:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00
2018-01-01 01:15:00
2018-01-01 01:30:00
```

But I would like it to be split into 2 columns and the characters like (`-, :`) be removed so that it is visible as follows:

```
Start_time             end_time
201801010000         201801010015
201801010015         201801010030
201801010030         201801010045
201801010045         201801010100
201801010100         201801010115
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You set the datetime format as `datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, so just change into `datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for change format of `date`s, then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column:

```
start_date = '2019-03-05 00:00:00'
end_date = '2019-03-06 00:00:00'
#change resolution by removing s
resolution = '15min'

dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq = resolution)
dates = pd.Series(dates).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')

df = pd.concat([dates,dates.shift(-1)],axis=1, keys=('Start_time','end_time'))
print (df)
      Start_time      end_time
0   201903050000  201903050015
1   201903050015  201903050030
2   201903050030  201903050045
3   201903050045  201903050100
4   201903050100  201903050115
..           ...           ...
92  201903052300  201903052315
93  201903052315  201903052330
94  201903052330  201903052345
95  201903052345  201903060000
96  201903060000           NaN

[97 rows x 2 columns]
```

If need remove last row add [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.concat([dates,dates.shift(-1)],axis=1, keys=('Start_time','end_time')).iloc[:-1]
print (df)
      Start_time      end_time
0   201903050000  201903050015
1   201903050015  201903050030
2   201903050030  201903050045
3   201903050045  201903050100
4   201903050100  201903050115
..           ...           ...
91  201903052245  201903052300
92  201903052300  201903052315
93  201903052315  201903052330
94  201903052330  201903052345
95  201903052345  201903060000

[96 rows x 2 columns]
```

Another idea is use `DataFrame` constructor, difference with solutions above there is last value of `end_time` different:

```
start_date = '2019-03-05 00:00:00'
end_date = '2019-03-06 00:00:00'
resolution = '15min'

dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq = resolution)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start_time':dates.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M'),
                   'end_time': (dates + pd.to_timedelta(resolution)).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')})

print (df)
      Start_time      end_time
0   201903050000  201903050015
1   201903050015  201903050030
2   201903050030  201903050045
3   201903050045  201903050100
4   201903050100  201903050115
..           ...           ...
92  201903052300  201903052315
93  201903052315  201903052330
94  201903052330  201903052345
95  201903052345  201903060000
96  201903060000  201903060015

[97 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

So you can just using `shift`

```
dates = pd.Series(dates)

df=pd.concat([dates,dates.shift()],axis=1).dropna()
```